# Expected expression before ‘{’ token in trying to initialize array of array of structs

Tags: c, arrays

My code is below.  On the lines marked with `*`'s, I get:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
rval.adj_list[0] = { {"B","C",3},{"B","A",2} };
```

Is there a compact way to initialize a dynamically allocated "double array" of pointers to pointers?

```
struct node;

struct edge {
    char *from;
    char *to;
    int weight;
};

struct digraph {
    char **vertices;
    struct edge **adj_list;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    struct digraph rval;
    int size = 5;
    rval.vertices = malloc( size * sizeof(char*));
    rval.adj_list = malloc( size * sizeof(struct edge*));
    rval.vertices[0] = "A";
    rval.adj_list[0] = { {"A","B",2},{"A","E",1} };  //********
    rval.vertices[1] = "B";
    rval.adj_list[1] = { {"B","C",3},{"B","A",2} };  //********
    rval.vertices[2] = "C";
    rval.vertices[3] = "D";
    rval.vertices[4] = "E";
}
```

Comment: What's `rval.vertices = malloc( size * sizeof(char*));`? `char*` here is just a pointer, not the length you need.

Comment: `char *` is a pointer, not an array.  arrays can be initialized with `=  {data};` , but not assigned.  You're attempting to assign `= {data}` to a pointer, which is violates both of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need a C99 'compound literal', which looks like a cast followed by an initializer in braces.

```
rval.adj_list[0] = (struct edge []){ {"A","B",2},{"A","E",1} };
```

This leads to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node;

struct edge {
    char *from;
    char *to;
    int weight;
};

struct digraph {
    char **vertices;
    struct edge **adj_list;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct digraph rval;
    int size = 5;
    rval.vertices = malloc( size * sizeof(char*));
    rval.adj_list = malloc( size * sizeof(struct edge*));
    rval.vertices[0] = "A";
    rval.adj_list[0] = (struct edge[]){ {"A","B",2}, {"A","E",1} };
    rval.vertices[1] = "B";
    rval.adj_list[1] = (struct edge[]){ {"B","C",3}, {"B","A",2} };
    rval.vertices[2] = "C";
    rval.vertices[3] = "D";
    rval.vertices[4] = "E";
}
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could up vote this again. This comes up more often than people admit, and usually those that don't know how to do it often hack up middle-man solutions.

Comment: One thing eludes me. Both the types in the compound literal *and* the structure definition should be `const`, shouldn't they ? I would think it mattered (and I always do them that way) but i noticed they aren't here. Just curious.

Comment: If you can work out the correct mix of `const` qualifiers, be my guest to take the answer over. It isn't trivial to add them.  The `adjlist` element itself must be writable; the array it points to, and the items that each element in the array point to, are not modifiable, strictly.

Answer (score 2):

You could only initialize a whole structure in C99 mode preceding it by `(struct edge[])`. Otherwise you will have to initialize each member by itself:

```
rval.adj_list[0] = (struct edge[]){ {"A","B",2}, {"A","E",1} };
...
rval.adj_list[1] = (struct edge[]){ {"B","C",3}, {"B","A",2} };
```

Or:

```
rval.vertices[0] = "A";
rval.adj_list[0][0].from = "A";
rval.adj_list[0][0].to = "B";
rval.adj_list[0][0].weight = 2;
rval.adj_list[0][1].from = "A";
rval.adj_list[0][1].to = "E";
rval.adj_list[0][1].weight = 1;
rval.vertices[1] = "B";
rval.adj_list[1][0].from = "B";
rval.adj_list[1][0].to = "C";
rval.adj_list[1][0].weight = 3;
rval.adj_list[1][1].from = "B";
rval.adj_list[1][1].to = "A";
rval.adj_list[1][1].weight = 2;
```